# Why does my code say System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' when I leave the text box blank and click the submit button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET webform that takes a user entered number in a textbox with id="pin" and retrieves values which are inserted into other text boxes from my SQL database. Everything works fine except that if I leave the pin text box blank and click submit it returns System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' How can I fix this? I tried the code

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pin.Text) || pin.Text == "0")
            {
                //Alert user string is either null, empty or 0
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Please enter your pin');", true);
            }
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this issue?

Here's my full code for reference.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace Test
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-HOB2BSG\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dogdata;Integrated Security=True";


        protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) from dbo.tUser where pin = @pin", sqlCon);
                sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pin", Int32.Parse(pin.Text.Trim()));

                var count = (int)sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();

                if (count > 0)
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Collecting Data');", true);

                    // Insert IMEI, Sim, and DeviceNumber into corresponding textboxes
                    string sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT IMEI, Sim, DeviceNumber FROM dbo.tUser WHERE Pin =" + int.Parse(pin.Text);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectQuery, sqlCon);
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        IMEI.Text = (dr["IMEI"].ToString());
                        Sim.Text = (dr["Sim"].ToString());
                        DeviceNumber.Text = (dr["deviceNumber"].ToString());
                    }

                }
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pin.Text) || pin.Text == "0")
                {
                    //Alert user string is either null, empty or 0
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Please enter your pin');", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Please enter your pin');", true);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You have to test `string.IsNullOrEmpty(pin.Text)` **before** calling `Int32.Parse(pin.Text.Trim())`.

Comment: You have to validate the user's input. If you call Int32.Parse(pin.Text.Trim()) with an empty string in pin, the error you mention will be thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to validate if this string is a valid numeric value before you cast it to int, you coud do this in a single line line this

You can club the test to one line like this  `Int32.TryParse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(pin.text) ? "0" : pin.text)`

however if the pin textbox contains non numeric string this will throw an error

A safer solution would be to use TryParse method like this

```
int pinNumber = 0;
bool isValidPinNubmer;

isValidPinNubmer = Int32.TryParse(pin.text,out pinNumber)
```

this would both validate the pin number and cast the value and in case of non numeric value the pinNumber variable will be zero , hope this helps